# If then conditional logic in regex in python

Tags: python, pandas, regex, conditional-statements, series

I am attempting to implement a conditional statement within regex, applied via the [pandas.Series.str.extractall](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) method. Given the reading I've done [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html), this seems like a pretty easy problem to solve, but I am still getting stuck...

I have the following regex in the [Pythex tester](https://pythex.org/):

`(a)(?(1)b|c)`

As I understand it, `(a)` is my first test group. The conditional block `(?(1)b|c)` should attempt to match "b" if my first test group is a match, or else it will attempt to match "c". The results I am hoping for are as follows:

1. "b" = No Match
2. "ab" = Match
3. "c" = Match
4. "ac" = No Match

The `(a)(?(1)b|c)` statement achieves 1, 2, and 4, but it misses 3... Any tips?

Thank you!

Comment: Something like `^(a)?(?(1)b|c)` seems to work.

Comment: Yep that handles this test case I've posted here! That anchor really makes a difference. Thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: No problem! The anchor is important, but arguably more important is that I have made `(a)` into an optional capturing group, which makes the conditional possible in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the matches, you don't need a conditional.

If a, then also match b.. else match c, can be written as:

```
\b(?:ab|c)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EoZA9S/1)

Answer (score 1):

I am not seeing how your code matches up with [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).
It supplies id `1`, fine.

> Will try to match with yes-pattern if the group with given id ... exists, ...

> For example, `(<)?(\w+@\w+(?:\.\w+)+)(?(1)>|$)`

Notice how the example's group 1 is optional,
it matches or it doesn't and then we move on for more matching.

In your `(a)` expression the "a" is non-optional.
I would expect that group 1 always exists
at the point that we're evaluating the conditional.
Which makes it not especially conditional.

Start with `(a)?` to improve matters.

Comment: Agreed on changing ```(a)``` to ```(a)?```.  Let me phrase the behavior I am looking for differently (I am suspecting it is not available in the re package given [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax))

I want a statement that will check for the existence of *either* ```(1)b``` or ```c```, but not check for both.

Comment: To clarify, if group 1 is a match, I want to check for the existence of ```b```, and if group 1 is not a match, I want to check for the existence of ```c```. I *do not* want to proceed through all options until one or none are satisfied, which seems to be the default behavior.

Comment: I'm hearing you say this: `(a)?(?(1)b|c)`